# Can i collect the output of find(\&wanted, @directories) in an array

Tags: perl

I am writing a script which will traverse the directory(including subdir also) and push the desired file in an array so that i can work on each file.

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $path = $ARGV[0];
find({ wanted => \&GetappropriateFile }, $path);

sub GetappropriateFile
{
  my $file = $_;
  my @all_file;
 # print "$file\n";
  if ( -f and /traces[_d+]/)
  {
   #print "$file\n";
     open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "cannot open file:$!\n";
      while( my $line = <$fh>){
      $line =~ /Cmd\sline:\s+com.android*/;
      push(@all_file,$file);
      #print "$file\n";
    }
close($fh);
#print"@all_file\n";
  }

 }
```

**Problem Area** : my $file = $_;

Instead of using " $file" if i could get a way to use an array here then i can easily read those files one by one and filter it.

Here what i am tring to do is : I have to open each file and check for the string "Cmd line: com.android" as soon as i get this string in the file i have to push this current file in an array and start reading the another file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to avoid global vars.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find qw( find );

sub IsAppropriateFile {
  my ($file) = @_;
  if (-f $file && $file =~ /traces[_d+]/) {
    open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "cannot open file:$!\n";
    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
      if ($line =~ /Cmd\sline:\s+com.android*/) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
} 

{
  my $path = $ARGV[0];
  my @matching_files;
  find({
    wanted => sub {
      push @matching_files, $_ if IsAppropriateFile($_);
    },
  }, $path);

  print("$_\n") for @matching_files;  # Or whatever.
}
```

Comment: is it really need for using flower braces i mean line 20 and line 31.

Comment: @Maverick “curly braces” – yes, they make sense here as they restrict the visibility of the `$path` and `@matching_files` variables. They are not necessary, but it's a good practice (Perl has block scope, so their visibility ends at the closing brace).

Comment: @Maverick, The whole point of the answer is to show how the variable collecting the names doesn't have to be a global, so the curlies are relevant to the answer in that they highlight this. (I personally always use them in my programs for a number of reasons.)

Comment: @ikegam.. i m getting this error "odd number of elements in anonymous hash" when i search about this error then came to know that  "wanted => sub {" we something we are doing wrong

Comment: @Maverick, I was missing a "}", and you added it to the wrong place. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Put declaration of `@all_file` outside of function, and use it after `find()` finishes,

```
my @all_file;
sub GetappropriateFile
{
  .. 
}
```

You could also stop with file reading after successful match,

```
if ($line =~ /Cmd\sline:\s+com.android*/) {
  push(@all_file, $file);
  last;
}
```

Comment: Here my question is can i iterate one my one on each file if yes then how?

Comment: @Maverick you can use `@all_file` after `find()` is done with traversing.